# Dropdown menu not working (tab focus)

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im using a bootstrap example with a dropdown menu

Here the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/p73vc8Lv/

what im trying to do is to display the `dropdown menu` when the user tab on the link, Im tried with css and javascript

CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle a:focus > .dropdown-menu { display:block }
```

is there a way to do this? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you explain better what you want?

Comment: i wan to tap (keyboard button) doing this the user will navigate the menu without using the mause, but the problem is that when I tab over the dropdown opcion, nothing happen you have to press enter to display the options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but, if you want the dropdown to toggle when you tab onto it, you can do the following using javascript,

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        $(this).dropdown('toggle');
    }
});
```

Here's an example, http://jsfiddle.net/p73vc8Lv/3/

Comment: If I want to toggle back the menu, do I need to create another if statement ?

Comment: This code is really specific to this case and there are many (probably better) ways to do this, but here's one way to toggle the dropdown once you leave it, http://jsfiddle.net/p73vc8Lv/8

Answer (score 0):

Try this no need to add custom JS:

EXAMPLE:

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
              </div>
            </nav>
```